# Is this definition of group isomorphism correct?

Tags: group-theory, definition

Definition : $(G,\circ)$ and $(H,\circ)$  and suppose that their underlying set is $\Omega = \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. We say that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic if there exists a bijection from $\phi : \Omega \mapsto \Omega$ such that $\forall a,b \in G,\phi(a\circ b) = \phi(a) \circ \phi(b) $

**Question :** Is this definition of group isomorphism correct? Is according to my definition $G$ is always going to isomorphic to $H$?

Comment: The definition is correct (and standard). The operation for $G$ need not be the same as the operaton for $H$. In particular, there are two ways to define multiplication on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to make it a group (i.e,, there are two groups of order $4$, which are not isomorphic to each other).

Comment: @quasi But in that case there are no bijective homomorphisms, so that's not a counterexample.

Comment: @Arthur: I think that's what I'm saying. That you can't get a counterexample just by using a bijection.

Comment: So you have two groups $(\Omega,\times)$ and $(\Omega,\circ)$ of order $n$ and say they are isomorphic if there is a bijective homomorphism between them (but you used the same operation symbol twice)

Comment: You're saying that the two groups are $(G, \circ)$ and $(H, \circ)$, but that the underlying sets are the same. In that notation, $G$ and $H$ usually signify the underlying sets, and if they're the same you ought to say so. You should really have written $(\Omega, \circ)$ and $(\Omega, \circ)$. But wait, now those two are exactly the same. You should also have used a different operation symbol for the second one: $(\Omega, \circ)$ and $(\Omega, \times)$. There, that's better.

Comment: It is not really correct because you appear to be assuming that $G$ and $H$ are finite, which is not necessarily true.